# undercurrent - a few tweaks to the user interface of Stack Overflow

Tags: script, chrome-extensions

Websites evolve and so does StackOverflow. However sometimes it takes a while for features to mature fully and being subjected to involuntary beta tests can be frustrating.

Since merely moaning about it would make little difference, I rolled up my sleeves and created a [Google Chrome extension called undercurrent](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent) for disabling a few personal "favourites".

[image: undercurrent]

Its newest release can:

- clear search strings from searchbox
- clear gravatar shadows
- disable searchbox animation (obsolete)
- remove graphics next to username in the header (obsolete)
- disable the quick report hovercard in the header (obsolete)

[Downloads are available at its website](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent).

Feedback and ideas for additional tweaks are welcome, just drop a comment.

<sub>*Note: Hair-covered toads are not affiliated with the topic in any way.*</sub>

---

## Update 6

[undercurrent](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent) 1.0.9 is out.

- removed tweak for sharing buttons as it no longer serves any purpose

---

## Update 5

[undercurrent](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent) 1.0.8 is out. It's an improvement release:

- hides Google+ in addition to other sharing buttons

---

## Update 4

[undercurrent](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent) 1.0.7 is out. It's a bugfix release:

- resolves a race condition on page loads

Unfortunately the autoupdate feature isn't working yet, so get rid of the old version before installing the newer one.

---

## Update 3

[undercurrent](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent) 1.0.6 is out and contains a new tweak:

- hide the sharing buttons

Unfortunately the autoupdate feature isn't working yet, so get rid of the old version before installing the newer one.

---

## Update 2

[undercurrent](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent) 1.0.5 is out and contains a new tweak:

- clear gravatar shadows

Unfortunately the autoupdate feature isn't working yet, so get rid of the old version before installing the newer one.

---

## Update 1

[undercurrent](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent) 1.0.4 is out and contains several significant improvements:

1. individual tweaks can be turned on and off (Extensions -> undercurrent -> Options)
2. undercurrent is now compatible with most Q&A sites on the network
3. bugfixes (login and page lifecycle issues)

Unfortunately the autoupdate feature isn't working yet, so get rid of the old version before installing the newer one.

Comment: Hmm. This disables the disorienting search bar motion? **I'll have to install it immediately, on every computer I ever touch.** But what about the other features? Can I turn them back on if I happen to like them? And what is the "triangle before username"? I don't have/see a triangle before my/others user name(s).

Comment: (Also, btw, moaning *does* make a difference. Check out my list of moans (err, questions) on Meta.SO.)

Comment: @Cody Gray: Currently it's all features or nothing. I'm planning on adding an item-by-item configuration page, though. Maybe next week or so. Even the core functionality is still a bit rough on the edges (some weird timing issues with page loads). Too bad this post got booted off from Meta.. a lot less activity here.

Comment: @Cody Gray: The (downpointing) triangle is (was) located left of username link on the top bar.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Try the next version: less bugs, more sites and configurable tweaks.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for adding configurable options. Too bad I can only give a single +1.